# MomentJS resetting/reusing DOM element to display new time

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I've struggled with this on 3 projects now and have abandoned the concept entirely each time. I want to have a single DOM element called `general_current-time` that can be dynamically changed to match the active location's current time.

What currently happens is the first run will execute as expected, but any attempts to replace it will still continue to iterate through the first requested time.

I've tried clearing the field or replacing the text before starting a new interval.

Is there maybe a way to stop the interval and create a new one?

**Sample Below (updated):**

```
    function getTime(timezone) {
        stopTime(currTime);
        switch (timezone) {
            case 'Eastern':
                var b = "America/New_York"
                break;
            case 'Central':
                var b = "America/Mexico_City"
                break;
            case 'Mountain':
                var b = "America/Denver"
                break;
            case 'Pacific':
                var b = "America/Los_Angeles"
                break;
            case 'Arizona':
                var b = "America/Phoenix"
                break;
        }
        var currTime = setInterval(function () {
            var a = new moment().tz(b).format('hh:mm:ss a');
            $('#general_current-time').text(a);
        }, 1000)
    }

    function stopTime(currTime) {
        $('#general_current-time').text('Resetting..');
        clearInterval(currTime);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit - but it may also help to show how `getTime` is being called. If possible, edit your code to be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added to edit, I'll write something up.

Comment: This pen represents the issue I'm facing anyways, but I struggled to create something that's totally accurate to what I'm trying to achieve. It should suffice, though, and if not I'll improve it. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OagXmY

If you click New York, then click Los Angeles you'll see the problem I'm facing. Using that and referencing my sample above should hopefully clear some things up.

Comment: This is an issue with which scope. When you declare `var interval`, that variable is scoped to the function that it is in. You need to ensure that you both clear the current interval when you click on a button, and start a new one. I've edited your codepen here: https://codepen.io/chazsolo/pen/jQwMVL

Comment: Okay, this at least proves that what I'm trying to achieve will absolutely work, but I think I've over-nested some things and confused myself so I'm going to start from scratch with this reference, thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! I've added the working example into my answer so we can see it in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store a reference to `setInterval` if you want to clear it.

```
var timer = setInterval(...)
```

I would also suggest putting the logic of this into a separate function to call when needed, and caching your jQuery selectors. It's extra work checking the timezone on every single iteration of the timer (I doubt the client is changing timezones often, if ever), and increasing the delay to match the precision of your display (in this case you show precision to seconds but you call the interval 10 times per second; that means 9 out of 10 calls are superfluous)

```
// cache timezone 
var zone = {
  'Eastern': 'America/New York',
  'Central': 'America/Mexico_City',
  'Mountain': 'America/Denver',
  'Pacific': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'Arizona': 'America/Phoenix'
}[data.Timezone];

// cache DOM element to update
var $time = $('#general_current-time');

function updateTime() {
  $time.text(moment().tz(zone).format('hh:mm:ss a'));
}

// store a reference to the timer. Also, since the format precision is
// seconds, only run this every ~1000ms
var interval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

*Note that `updateTime` is impure because it's using `zone` and `$time` from it's parent scope, so there's definitely some improvements that can be made to that function.*

This will allow you to stop the timer and begin a new one:

```
// stop the interval using the timer reference
clearInterval(interval);

var newInterval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

---

**Full Program (from codepen)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let interval;

  $("#la").click(function() {
    clear(interval);

    interval = setInterval(function() {
      $("#time").text(
        moment()
        .tz("America/Los_Angeles")
        .format("hh:mm:ss a")
      );
    });
  });

  $('#east').click(function() {
    clear(interval);

    interval = setInterval(function() {
      $('#time').text(moment().tz('America/New_York').format('hh:mm:ss a'));
    });
  });

  $('#clear').click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});

function clear(interval) {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<p id="time">00:00</p>
<button id="la">Arizona</button>
<button id="east">East</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: I'll update my code here, I have tried this to no avail.

Comment: I'm trying to apply your logic here now, but by doing this its not dynamic, after 2 intervals that's it if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: Take a look at the updated codepen I commented on your question. The code I provided in my answer is just the pieces you need, it isn't organized into a functional program. I can update my answer if that helps.

Comment: The issue was in fact scope. I was clearing my interval after a new interval had already started, so moving the `clearInterval(currTime)` and the function itself up to happen on the search event let it clear to make room for the new interval to start.